# How to format date in listing page

Tags: php, date, formatting, yii, listings

I am new to Yii framework and just started to work on an existing website. I have a listing page and my requirement was to add a new field 'review_date_time' and I could managed to display it in listing. Now my question is how to change the format of the date and how to show a white space if date is not there in table field.Right now it is displaying 0000-00-00 00:00:00 if no date is there.

My code for listing

```
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'series-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'filter' => $model,
    'columns' => array(
                    array('header' => 'Category', 'name' => 'category.title'),
                    'exam_year',
                    'title',
                    'review_date_time',
                    array(
                        'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
                    ),
    ),
 ));
```

Comment: there could be something else other than nullDisplay, check out the modified answer, comment for feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is showing *0000-00-00 00:00:00* then it means that, that value is the default value in the db table, hence you'll have to use the [`value` property](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataColumn#value-detail) of CDataColumn:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
 'id' => 'series-grid',
 'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
 'filter' => $model,
 // 'nullDisplay'=>'',
 'columns' => array(
                array('header' => 'Category', 'name' => 'category.title'),
                'exam_year',
                'title',
                // 'review_date_time',
                array(
                    'name'=>'review_date_time',
                    'value'=>'$data->review_date_time=="0000-00-00 00:00:00"?"":$data->review_date_time'
                )
                array(
                    'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
                ),
 ),
));
```

Or try the [`nullDisplay` property](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#nullDisplay-detail) of CGridView (if you are storing null and overriding afterFind to format null as 0000-00-00 00:00:00):

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id' => 'series-grid',
'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
'filter' => $model,
'nullDisplay'=>'',
'columns' => array(
                array('header' => 'Category', 'name' => 'category.title'),
                'exam_year',
                'title',
                'review_date_time',
                array(
                    'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
                ),
 ),
));
```

Comment: let me know how that works out for you, if it doesn't work there is another method

Comment: Yes, it worked for me. Before my field default value was none. Now I changed it to null and this nullDisplay worked for me. Can you help me to format the date too ?  In column array I tried like this array('name' => 'review_date_time', 'value' => date('m/d/Y h:i:s A', $model->review_date_time), but it gave am error.

Comment: ok, the value is supposed to be `public string $value;` hence you'll need to use quotes, check how i have done it in the answer. for now you can use `'value' => 'date("m/d/Y h:i:s A", $model->review_date_time)'`

Comment: Many thanks for the help, but date format did not work for me.it returned this for all entries -  01/01/1970 05:30:00 AM

Comment: you can try [date format](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFormatter#dateFormat-detail), google for examples on how to use it

Comment: i just noticed that you were passing `$model->review_date_time` but you should be passing `$data->review_date_time` , and if the values in db are not stored as timestamps(i.e number of seconds from epoch) then you also need to convert mysql datetime to unix timestamp, so finally you should be using: `'value' => 'date("m/d/Y h:i:s A", strtotime($data->review_date_time))'`, with this exact line, it'll work, try and let me know