# Yii: how to format a mysql datestamp according to locale?

Tags: formatting, yii, datestamp

I'm at my first day with Yii

I've just learned how to filter columns

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('User', 
            array(
                'criteria' => array(
                                'select' => 'id, username, realname, email, companyId, languageId, registrationDate',
                                'order' => 'username ASC',
                                )
                 )
    );
    $this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
```

Now  I've a problem: **the 'registrationdDate' is a MySql datestamp.**

So i need to show localized... how can I do this ?

the code of the view is a   list. I'm listing using this:

```
<td><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->registrationDate); ?></td>
```

What can be done to detect user locale? And how to format a "2012-10-13 13:33:45", for example, into the correct localized string?

For italian it will be 13/10/2012 or 13-10-2012  with appended 13:33:45

Comment: I know this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662555/yii-framework-how-to-format-date-in-listing-page?rq=1 but I don't understand ...

Comment: Show us a place where you display that value.

Comment: I added the view code where to apply the formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would be:

```
<td>
        <?php echo Yii::app()->locale->dateFormatter
                  ->formatDateTime($data->registrationDate); ?>
</td>
```

Comment: This cannot auto-localize the date format. I know Yii knows that language user is using, and I read that is a way to use a native Yii method to formate date .... or not ?